# How to parse an array of json object in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following  array of json object

`[{"id":10,"name":"sinu"},{"id":20,"name":"shinto"}]`

How can i parse this using jquery and get  names, id  of each one.

thanks in advance

Comment: No such thing in JavaScript as "JSON object". There is JSON (which is a particularly formatted string), and there is JS object (which is a type in JavaScript). Which one of those do you have? And what is the output you want, since the description is similarly vague? (EDIT: there actually does exist a JSON object: `JSON` (the one with `parse` and `stringify` functions; I am 100% positive that's not what you are talking about)

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(jsoninfo);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"id":10,"name":"sinu"},{"id":20,"name":"shinto"}];
    jQuery(data).each(function(i, item){
        $('#output').append(item.id + ' ' + item.name + '<br>');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

```
var data = [{"id":10,"name":"sinu"},{"id":20,"name":"shinto"}];
jQuery(data).each(function(i, item){
    console.log(item.id, item.name)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json2.js and parse your array of json object. See the working code below,

```js
var data = '[{"id":10,"name":"sinu"},{"id":20,"name":"shinto"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

var append= '';

$.each(obj, function(i, $val)
  {
    append+= $val.id + ',';
  });
       
$('#ids').text(append);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js"></script>

<label id='ids'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`jQuery.parseJSON()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/):

```
var arr = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{"id":10,"name":"sinu"},{"id":20,"name":"shinto"}]' );

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('index: ' + i + ', id: ' + arr[i].id + ', name: ' + arr[i].name);
}
```

That code will log this to your console:

```
index: 0, id: 10, name: sinu
index: 1, id: 20, name: shinto
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to iterate over your json object using each function and get the values.

```
$.each(jsonObject,function(i.field){
id=field.id;
name=field.name;
});
```

or 
can get Array of objects using
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObject))